All my 240 appliances stopped working after ther oven blew it's breaker
Turned the oven on and 20 seconds later the breaker blew. Now all the 240 appliances don't work. No other breakers were tripped. Every breaker reads 110 touching the neutral bar and the breaker contact water pump outside 240 doesn't work. 240 dryer doesn't work. 240 stove doesn't work. They all show 110 coming in on their black and reds.
it's a 200 amp panel. The only breaker that tripped was for the oven. Every contact on every breaker reads 110. I disconnected the oven internally and flipped the breaker on and it did not trip it again. So I assume the oven it self has the issue. But now why is all 240 appliances not working.

Did any breakers trip? Do any 120V circuits work?

240v uses two half's of two 120v panels.  If no 240v devices work and only half of the house 120v circuits work, then main breaker might be damaged.

check the main breaker, 100 amp one

@Traveler How do you know it is 100A and not 60A or 150A or 200A?

Thanks for commenting back, it's a 200 amp panel. The only breaker that tripped was for the over. Every contact on every breaker reads 110. I disconnected the oven internally and flipped the breaker on and it did not trip it again. So I assume the oven it self has the issue. But now why is all 240 appliances not working.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thanks for commenting back, it's a 200 amp panel. The only breaker that tripped was for the over. Every contact on every breaker reads 110. I disconnected the oven internally and flipped the breaker on and it did not trip it again. So I assume the oven it self has the issue. But now why is all 240 appliances not working.

some breakers do not show clearly when they are tripped. try to on/off

To protect your appliances turn off all the multi-pole (240v) breakers.
240v is delivered as two 120v legs, 180° out of orientation. One leg seems to be missing. Reading 0v measuring black to red, but 120v to ground on both the black and red is actually reading the same 120v feeding through the stove or other 240v appliance. Some of your 120v circuits are probably behaving badly by being fed through your 240v appliances, and those 120v circuits will completely cease to work when you turn off the 240v breakers.
First step is to reset the main breaker. Only one leg of a main breaker shouldn't trip, but I have seen it. If all your 120's come on then you can reset your 240's and you should be good to go. If that doesn't correct the situation then the next step is to determine if the fault is your panel or ahead of your panel. Here it gets a little tricky. You can call an electrician or the utility.
The utility normally will come out for free to determine if the problem is a utility or customer problem. But if everything is good on the utility side he will normally take the meter, leave you with no power, and make it harder for the electrician to isolate the problem.
If you call an electrician first he will likely bill you even if he determines the problem is utility, but it's easier for him to isolate a problem on the customer side if the utility is still on. With power off he is really only working with 95% probability. Good odds, but not perfect. With power off he will use a continuity meter to chase verify each point to see where flow is interrupted an can usually identify the problem, but sometimes things just behave different when the power is on.
